# Sending a yes/no from Excel 2007 to Access 2007 via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This is probably going to be a really stupid question, but I've had no luck researching it and it's probably easier then I'm making it.

I'm writing an excel spreadsheet, which will be able to add new products to an existing access database.  Everything works, except that when it posts the information it has to set the product 'active'.  Active is defined as a yes/no box in access.  I've tried sending the information as integer (1 or 0), yes/no and true false, but all of these return a Run-time error '3265': Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.

```
 Rs.Fields("ProdCode") = strProdcode
 Rs.Fields("Active") = 1
```

Comment: "*error '3265': Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.*" means that it's not finding a column with that name in the rowset/table.

Answer (score 0):

Excel and Access treat true as -1 and false as 0.

Answer (score 0):

MS-Access is using the values 0 and -1, not  .... Don't ask me why! Try it in the debug window:

```
? True = 1
? True = -1
? false = 0
```

So your code should say:

```
Rs.Fields("Active") = -1
```

Comment: This is the default behavior. MS Access Yes/No field means Yes = -1, and No = 0